# The Sobolev inequality extends to powers of function.

Tags: reference-request, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

Let $n\ge 2$ be a natural number and $p<n$. Suppose $f\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain.

Then, by the Sobolev inequality,
$$
||f||_{p^\ast} = ||f||_{\frac{np}{n-p}} \le C||{Df}||_{p}
$$
where $||\cdot||_q$ refers to the $L^q$-norm on $\Omega$.

> Does the Sobolev inequality remain valid for functions $|f|^\alpha$ when $f\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ and $\alpha \ge 1$. I.e. if $f\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ can I conclude that $|||f|^\alpha||_{p^\ast}\le C|| D(|f|^\alpha)||_p$? In particular, if the left hand side is infinite then so is the right-hand side.

I was thinking we can define $G_N : [0, \infty)\to [0, \infty)$ to be a $C^1$ function such that $G_N(x) = x^\alpha$ for $x \le N$, and $G_N$ is linear on $[N, \infty)$.

Then, given that $f \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ we also have $|f| \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and, since $G_N$ is $C^1$ with bounded derivtive and $G_N(0) = 0$, $G_N(|f|)\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Ergo,
$$
||G_N(|f|)||_{p^\ast}  \le C||D[G_N(|f|)]||_{p}.
$$
Letting $N\to\infty$ on either side (using the monotone convergence theorem), I should obtain
$$
|||f|^\alpha||_{p^\ast}\le C|| D(|f|^\alpha)||_p
$$

Comment: @daw $G_N^\prime(x) = \alpha x^{\alpha -1} \le \alpha N^{\alpha - 1}$ when $0 \le x\le N$. For $x\ge N$, $G_N$ was linearized so $G_N^\prime(x) = \alpha N^{\alpha - 1}$. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "remaining valid" for power functions? The final inequality $\lVert |f|^{\alpha} \rVert_{p^*} \leq \lVert D(|f|^{\alpha}) \rVert_p$ does hold true in general, but both sides need not be finite for general $f \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ and $\alpha>1$.

Comment: @ktoi I updated the question. Thank you. Will it still hold if the norms are not finite in the sense $\infty \le \infty$?